# WiFi not discovering networks Ubuntu 18.04 Macbook pro mid 2010

Tags: networking, 18.04, wireless, macbook-pro

I installed Ubuntu 18.04.03 LTS on a Macbook Pro mid 2010 (Broadcom 4322 [14e4:433b](rev 01)), but I haven't been able to  configure the WiFi. I did all the steps suggested here but I can't see any wifi network. I have followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1076964/macbook-can-t-find-wifi-for-ubuntu-18-04)  without success.

*NOTE: This is an old MacBook Pro from my wife that I am trying to give more useful life. I am connected via ethernet cable.*

The output I get from various commands is below:

```
$ sudo iw reg get
global
country US: DFS-FCC
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 30), (N/A)
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 23), (N/A), AUTO-BW
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 23), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 23), (0 ms), DFS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 30), (N/A)
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 40), (N/A)
```

```
$ nmcli dev wifi list
IN-USE  SSID  MODE  CHAN  RATE  SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY
```

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4322 802.11a/b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:432b] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. AirPort Extreme [106b:008d]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
    Kernel modules: ssb, wl
```

```
$ iwconfig
wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp3s0    no wireless extensions.
```

```
$ sudo iwlist chan
wlp2s0    32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 32 : 5.16 GHz
          Channel 34 : 5.17 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 38 : 5.19 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 42 : 5.21 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 46 : 5.23 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 50 : 5.25 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 54 : 5.27 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 58 : 5.29 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 62 : 5.31 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 66 : 5.33 GHz
          Channel 68 : 5.34 GHz
          Channel 70 : 5.35 GHz
          Channel 72 : 5.36 GHz
lo        no frequency information.

enp3s0    no frequency information.
```

```
$ rfkill list all
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy1: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
4: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -e 0200 -e 0280
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4322 802.11a/b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:432b] (rev 01)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme BCM5764M Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:1684] (rev 10)
```

[image: additional drivers configs]

[image: No wifi networks]

**EDIT1:**
Not sure if this help but:

```
$ grep -H b43 /etc/modprobe.d/*
/etc/modprobe.d/b43.config:options b43 pio=1
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf:blacklist b43
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf:blacklist b43legacy
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf:# replaced by b43 and ssb.
```

**EDIT 2:**
I opened this question after reading the guidelines. I have previously asked in here: [Ubuntu 18.04 WiFi Networks are not displaying even though there are 3 nearby](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1099383/ubuntu-18-04-wifi-networks-are-not-displaying-even-though-there-are-3-nearby/1188344#1188344)

Please let me know if I should ask this in ubuntuforum.
This is the text file from Wireless Info Github Ubuntu Forums
[OUTPUT OF Wireless Info github page](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1oemA-9qYYOAK6EU9P55mvtHOG6Lrj20S)

Answer (score 0):

After 10 days of trying different solutions, finally, it is working. 
The post here by  KiLLeRfriend is what solved my problem:

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1745437

I am copying here for future reference:

```
I fixed my problem with the Broadcom bcm4311 drivers on 11.04 (Natty Narwhal)

Steps I took for fixing this problem: (I stole this method from http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1700897[user:nm_geo; post #5])

-open the 'Synaptic Package Manager' and search for 'bcm'

-uninstall the 'bcm-kernel-source' package

-make sure that the 'firmware-b43-installer' and the 'b43-fwcutter' packages are installed

-type into terminal:

[cat /etc/modprobe.d/* | egrep '8180|acx|at76|ath|b43|bcm|CX|eth|ipw|irmware|isl| lbtf|orinoco|ndiswrapper|NPE|p54|prism|rtl|rt2|rt3 |rt6|rt7|witch|wl']

(you may want to copy this) and see if the term 'blacklist bcm43xx' is there

-if it is, [terminal]cd /etc/modprobe.d/ [and then]sudo gedit blacklist.conf

put a # in front of the line: blacklist bcm43xx

then save the file (I was getting error messages in the terminal about not being able to save, but it actually did save properly)

-reboot

-sudo iw reg set "REGION"

-reboot
```